# Checking if username, email and phone number data already exist in cloud firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to check if username, email and phone number data already exist in cloud firestore.

```
 private fun checkExistence(username: String, email: String, phonenumber: String): Boolean {
        val query: Query =
            db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("username", username).whereEqualTo("email", email)
                .whereEqualTo("phonenumber", phonenumber)
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                for (documentSnapshot in task.result!!) {
                    val userName = documentSnapshot.getString("username")
                    val userEmail = documentSnapshot.getString("email")
                    val userPhone = documentSnapshot.getString("phonenumber")
                    when {
                        userName == username -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "User Exists")
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Username exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        userEmail == email -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Email Exists")
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Email exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        userPhone == phonenumber -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Phone number Exists")
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Phone number exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (task.result!!.size() == 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User not Exists")
                //You can store new user information here
                Toast.makeText(this, "User not Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

I'm expecting a toast if each data exist, but the code is only executing the first check which is the username check, it is not checking for email or phone number.

Comment: Please edit the question to give more detail about what isn't working the way you expect.  "The code is only executing the first check" isn't very clear.  Are you expecting a different outcome?  What exactly?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm expecting a check for each case but it's only showing for username.

Comment: I'm still unclear when you mean by "check" and "each case".  Please **edit the question** (don't just add a comment) to say what you are expecting this query to do.  If it's not doing what you expect, please explain what is different.  It will help if you **give specific examples** with actual data.

Comment: I see that your method returns true no matter what is happening inside your callback. Is this what you want? Please also respond with @AlexMamo